# Why were Ali al-Rida coins continued to be minted after his death?

Tags: islamic-history, caliphate

In [this Iranian website](http://malekmuseum.org/news/1581/%D8%B3%DA%A9%D9%87-%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B1%D8%B6%D8%A7-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85#:%7E:text=%D8%B3%DA%A9%D9%87%20%D9%86%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%87%20%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%87%D8%AF%DB%8C%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%B1%D8%B6%D8%A7%20%28%D8%B9%29%20%D8%A8%D9%87%20%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%86,%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B3%DB%8C%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%2F%20%D8%B0%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%DB%8C%D9%86%C2%BB.) there's the following information:

> براساس اسناد تاریخی موجود، سکه‌های ولایتعهدی امام رضا (ع) در ضرابخانه‌های مرو، سمرقند، اصفهان، محمدیه (ری)، فارس و نیشابور در فاصله سال‌های ۲۰۱ تا ۲۰۵ هجری قمری ضرب شد که شماری از آن‌ها در کتابخانه و موزه ملی ملک و موزة‌ آستان قدس رضوی نگهداری می‌شود.

My translation: According to the historical documents coins were minted in the name of [Ali al-Rida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_al-Rida) (Abbasid Caliph al-Ma'mun's heir) in Merv, Samarkand, Isfahan, Ray, Fars, and Nishapur between 201 and 205 AH (Islamic calendar).

But Ali al-Rida was killed by al-Ma'mun in 203 AH (818 AD). So why were the coins still minted after his death? Why didn't al-Ma'mun order to recall those coins to mint a new coin? The coins continued to be minted for two years afer Ali al-Rida's death.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Theresa_thaler , the "Maria Theresa thaler" is still being minted, even though Maria Theresa died in 1780.

Comment: That's for sure in order to honor Maria Theresa thaler. But al-Ma'mun became an enemy of Ali al-Rida and killed him. So why were the coins minted for two years after his death?